# Not getting Tan (90) Value as undefined in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

While running below statement it prints the wrong value in the console. I got stuck as I am a beginner.

```
NSLog(@"tan(90)=%f",tan(90*M_PI/180.0);
```

Output displayed as : **tan(90)=16331239353195370.000000**

Comment: What is the expected result? The string suggests to print `NSLog(@"tan(90)=%f",tan(90.0);`

Comment: It should be infinite/Undefined ( should I make it execute  using If/Else )

Comment: Why? Did you check this with a calculator?

Comment: oh no i mean to say according to Trigonometry we get tan(90) = infinite. but if we do same in scientific calculator it shows 163312394e16. My question is how i should print tan(90) as undefined in console [Objective-c]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is correct. `M_PI / 2.0` is a `double` that is quite close to π/2, but is not *precisely* π/2 (π cannot be precisely represented by a `double`). Therefore its tangent is very large, but not infinite.

[schmitdt9's link to the `tan` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tan) are useful, but the important note is this one:

> The function has mathematical poles at π(1/2 + n); however no common floating-point representation is able to represent π/2 exactly, thus there is no value of the argument for which a pole error occurs.

"Pole" means "input for which the function is infinite."

To your question "how i should print tan(90) as undefined in console," the answer is you'll need to special-case it. Normalize whatever you've been passed to 0-360, and check if it's 90 or 270. If so, print `infinite`, otherwise call `tan`.

Answer (score 0):

`tan` is a C function, please refer to this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tan
Especially it is said:

> If a domain error occurs, an implementation-defined value is returned
>   (NaN where supported)

So I suppose the number 16331239353195370.000000 means Infinity/error in this case

**Edit**

About Infinity printing
There is a special macro `INFINITY` and if you do

```
NSLog(@"%f", INFINITY);
```

the output will be

```
inf
```